# Reduce space between columns in a table exported from Stata

Tags: tables, spacing, columns, stata

I have been trying to reduce the space between the columns in a table that was exported directly from Stata.

The table is the following:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Regression\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular*}{1.1\hsize}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{4}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule
```

I know I need to work with `\tabcolsep`  but I am not sure how to isolate it from that big piece of code I have already.

---

Following @leandriis feedback I replaced `1.1\hsize` with `\textwidth`, but that does not seem to work:
what I had:
[image: My output before]

I want the columns to be closer together, as that way it is out of the margins of the rest of my work.

And if I include `\textwidth`this is what I get:
[image: My output with textwidth]

---

My minimal working example as requested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\graphicspath{ {./mypath/} }
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}


\FloatBarrier
\begin{small}
     \input{\begin{table}[H]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Regression with country and year dummies\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular*}{1.1\hsize}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{4}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Group 1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Group 2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Group 3}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Group 4}\\
\midrule
propyes1            &       305.1\sym{***}&                     &                     &                     \\
                    &    (205.46)         &                     &                     &                     \\
\addlinespace
gdppc               &  -0.0000193\sym{***}&  0.00000260\sym{*}  &  -0.0000174\sym{***}&  -0.0000147\sym{***}\\
                    &    (-18.19)         &      (2.38)         &    (-16.38)         &    (-13.72)         \\
\addlinespace
propyes2            &                     &       17.19\sym{***}&                     &                     \\
                    &                     &     (75.74)         &                     &                     \\
\addlinespace
propyes3            &                     &                     &       9.964\sym{***}&                     \\
                    &                     &                     &     (40.51)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
propyes4            &                     &                     &                     &      -6.050\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &                     &    (-35.42)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &       13.66\sym{***}&       58.99\sym{***}&       60.07\sym{***}&       64.76\sym{***}\\
                    &     (84.14)         &    (541.52)         &    (478.00)         &    (667.77)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &      386364         &      386364         &      386364         &      386364         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}}

\end{small}
 \FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add, say just after `\begin{table}`, `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` (the default is 6pt).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What exactly should your output look like? Do you want a table that is as wide as the textwidth? If so, replace  `1.1\hsize`with `\textwidth`. With this adjustment, your table fits onto the page and at the same time, the distance between the columns is reduced. If you want your table to be as wide as it naturally is, you could give `\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}` a try.

Comment: @Bernard: Since the code uses `tabular*`in combination with `\extracolsep`, explicitly reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` won't make much of a difference here.

Comment: @Bernard Hello, and thank you for your quick reply! I have tried adding that, but should I then remove the ```\tabcolstep``` that appears in the middle of my code just like that? Because if I add it without touching anything else everything remains intact

Comment: the only reason to have `\begin{tabular*}{1.1\hsize}` is to force the column spacing to be larger than normal (and force the table to be wider than the page)

Comment: @leandriis: It seems I only skimmed through the code… Will try  not to do it again! ;o)

Comment: @pfragon: I don't think you need `tabcolsep` in your code (b.t.w. is is tabcolsep, not tabcolstep).

Comment: @leandriis I have followed your directions and updated my post with it! Thank you for your fast reply, but I would like to slightly make the columns come closer together and nothing is working. Thank you again!

Comment: @pfragon: Would you prepare a small [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including the documentclass as well as the code for the actual table? Aparently, the `D` column type is not set up correctly. Please also clarify: Do you want the table to be exactly as wide as the textwidth or do would you also be satisfied if it was narrower?

Comment: @leandriis Yes! I will get on it

Comment: use `\begin{tabular}` not `\begin{tabular*}{...}` then the table will be its natural width

Comment: @leandriis I would be happy if it was narrower, sorry for not specifying

Comment: No a "minimal working example"  means code that people can copy and debug, so no `[...]` and no `\input` of files we don't have.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, first timer here, will do it again then. And, if I replace tabular* by tabular, it gives me an error of illegal pream used with my instructions

Comment: @pfragon: Thanks for the update. However, the contents of the table seem to be cut off.

Comment: you need to remove the width argument, as I indicated.  `tabular` does not have a width specified. The columns are only separated as you are using tabular* and forcing them apart.

Comment: @leandriis Updated with the entire content, sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion beased on `siunitx`. (Red lines indicate page margins, Numbers are aligned with respect to the decimal separator, number of observations are horizontally centered within the corresponding columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Regression\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{S[table-format=-3.8,
                           input-symbols = {()},
                           table-space-text-pre=), 
                           table-space-text-post=\sym{***}, 
                           table-align-text-post=false, 
                           table-align-text-pre=false ]}@{}}
\toprule
                    &{(1)}&{(2)}&{(3)}&{(4)}\\
                    &{Group 1}&{Group 2}&{Group 3}&{Group 4}\\
\midrule
propyes1            &       305.1\sym{***}&                     &                     &                     \\
                    &    (205.46)         &                     &                     &                     \\
\addlinespace
gdppc               &  -0.0000193\sym{***}&  0.00000260\sym{*}  &  -0.0000174\sym{***}&  -0.0000147\sym{***}\\
                    &    {(}-18.19)         &      (2.38)         &    {(}-16.38)         &    {(}-13.72)         \\
\addlinespace
propyes2            &                     &       17.19\sym{***}&                     &                     \\
                    &                     &     (75.74)         &                     &                     \\
\addlinespace
propyes3            &                     &                     &       9.964\sym{***}&                     \\
                    &                     &                     &     (40.51)         &                     \\
\addlinespace
propyes4            &                     &                     &                     &      -6.050\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &                     &    {(}-35.42)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &       13.66\sym{***}&       58.99\sym{***}&       60.07\sym{***}&       64.76\sym{***}\\
                    &     (84.14)         &    (541.52)         &    (478.00)         &    (667.77)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &      {386364}         &      {386364}         &      {386364}         &      {386364}         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the work and patience! That works perfectly for what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

```
\begin{tabular*}{1.1\hsize}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{4}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
```

specifies that latex should stretch the table so the columns are far apart and the total width of the table is 10% wider than fits on the page.

use

```
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
```

So that the table is natural width.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply, that does seem to work, but I want to narrow down the space between columns. Any way to do that by changing from tabular* to tabular?

Comment: @pfragon that presumably already makes the space between columns less as you are no longer stretching the table but you can put `\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}` immediately before `\begin{tabular}` if you want to squeeze it more or replace -1 by 2.8 or whatever format works best in the `D` column specification.